# How can I print the name of each file that is being assessed in a for loop (linux)

Tags: linux, for-loop, filenames

I'm not quite sure how to print the file name being processed from within a for loop in linux. I realize that similar questions have been asked, but I haven't successfully adapted any of the suggested responses yet.

I'm trying to entries in a file and output the file name. Each individual entry is made up of 4 lines, which is the reason that I’m dividing by 4. I can easily count the entries via:

```
for i in *.gz; do expr $(cat $i | wc -l) / 4; done
```

But how can I output the filename?

Thanks for your help!
Ryan

Comment: Isn't it just: `echo "$i"`?

Comment: What @kaylum said ... what you're actually running is printing the quarter of the lines in each file you're iterating over, whatever sense that may make on a gzipped file ...

Comment: Yes, I am counting something that iterates every fourth line. But where in the for loop do I type the echo "$i"? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to that effect? As it stands it's quite confusing.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
for i in *.gz
do 
  echo "$i"
  expr $(cat "$i" | wc -l) / 4
done
```

Comment: Thanks! That does help. I’m used to running the for loop as a single line, and I was having trouble doing it that way. It seems I can do this by adding in another semicolon.

Comment: You can indeed, and glad it helped you. :)